# How to change the src of a img with its alt?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Is there way to change the image `src` attribute with its `alt` attribute on load of the image?

I want the script to automatically change the image's source to the image's alt.

*Before*

```
<img src="" alt="exe">
```

*After*

```
<img src="exe" alt="exe">
```

Comment: exe? Is this code supposed to be malicious?

Comment: Divya is usually a female's name.

Comment: that's not the purpose of the alt attribute... use a custon attribute instead...  data-off="..." data-on="..." for example.  "data-" is intended to be the prefix for non-standard meta data in tags.  If you exend the question a better answer may be provided.  Are you using an underlying toolkit (jquery, dojo, etc?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use JavaScript:

```
// Execute function on load through self-invocation
var switchAlt = function() {
    // Get all images on the document
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

    // Count the number of image elements and switch alt and src
    var i = images.length;
    while (i--) {
        images[i].src = images[i].alt;
    }
}();
```

Don't forget to wrap it into script tags if you're implementing it in HTML files:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Execute function on load through self-invocation
var switchAlt = function() {
    // Get all images on the document
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

    // Count the number of image elements and switch alt and src
    var i = images.length;
    while (i--) {
        images[i].src = images[i].alt;
    }
}();
</script>
```

Comment: Quick note: If the OP wants to swap them ,you're going to want to use a temporary variable in that while loop.

Comment: @apphacker - What's wrong with using an abstraction that makes the coding simpler?

Comment: @jmort253, overhead. Loading a library for trivial code is redundant.

Comment: @jmort253 There's nothing wrong with it, the original question didn't ask for it. If he or she isn't using jQuery and doesn't know anything about it, it's a useless answer.

Comment: I know people mentioned it in the question's comments, but it might be worth mentioning in the answer that while you can do it, it's not really the correct usage of the `alt` attribute

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var change = function() {
    var imgs = document.images || document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgs[i].src = imgs[i].alt;
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mSZw5/)**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, give the id of the image so img tag will look like this:

```
<img id="img1" src="" alt="myimage.jpg" onload = "changesource()"/>
```

Now write a JavaScript function like this:

```
function changeSrc()
{
    var img = document.getElementById("img1");
    img.src =img.alt;
}
```

Now call this function on the load of image like this:

```
onload = "changeSrc()"
```

Comment: According to this resource, this isn't reliable in all browsers:  http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/images/_IMG_onLoad.html